# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 on linux

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I'll admit it... I'm a n00b in the linux world, but I'm curious to find out if it's possible to run my ASP.NET MVC 3.0 web applications on linux.

Can anybody direct me to or write a guide for n00bs like me that explains *thoroughly* the entire process of installing mono, apache and/or any other components that are required?

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole section on the mono web dedicated to [mono-ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

Also, you can download (from the [mono download page](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)) a linux virtual image with pre-installed mono and use that for experiments and reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://twistedcode.net/blog/post/2011/01/17/Mono-and-ASPNET-MVC-v3.aspx) is an article about running ASP.NET MVC 3 web applications on mono.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Ubuntu-LTS version

```
apt-get install mono-complete
apt-get install monodevelop
apt-get install mono-vbnc
apt-get install mono-xsp*
apt-get install fastcgi-mono-server*

apt-get install nginx
```

In your MVC-project, do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono/6317712#6317712